# Em-based measurements and jerky CSS transitions in WebKit browsers

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I'm trying to do something where it is convenient to specify coordinates in EMs and transition  `font-size` to show my content at different sizes (it's a sort of block-based-graphics thing).

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem. It's fine in Firefox, there's no transition in IE (which is fine), but in Safari and Chrome it does a crazy jerky thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/6pf3D/2/

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.parent{
    -webkit-transition: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 10s;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
    font-size:16px;
    width:16em;
    height:16em;
}
.child{
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    width: 8em;
    height:8em;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('.parent').css('font-size', '32px');
```

Does anybody know how I can get a smooth transition without sacrificing em-based coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've made a new 1, try it out

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pf3D/3/)(2 sec Interval)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pf3D/5/)(10 second interval)

CSS

```
.parent{
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3);
    font-size:16px;
    width:16em;
    height:16em;
    transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -moz-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -webkit-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -o-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
}

.child{
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
    width: 8em;
    height:8em;
    transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -moz-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -webkit-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
    -o-transition: width 10s, height 10s;
}
```

Comment: Yep seems like putting a transition on the child element is the way forward (I was just trying that out). Will accept this.

Comment: @MichaelForrest happy transitions :)